# How to open and use an .Rda file

Tags: r, rda

I am writing multiple RDA files to my computer and trying to open them again. For example, I save a data frame called 'geocode' as:

```
dim(geocode)
save(geocode, file=paste0("[path]/geocodenew.Rda"))
```

I can see the file saved, about 30 KB, on my computer. But then I try to access it later I get:

```
load("[path]/geocodenew.Rda")
geocodenew
```

And I get the error:

> "Error: object 'geocodenew' not found."

What am I doing wrong?

(I am eventually going to use this to stack multiple dataframes using `rbind()` if that helps at all)

Comment: the name in the environment after `load`  shld be just `geocode` if that's what it was when you `save`d it. Do `(load("[path]/geocodenew.Rda"))` and see what you get printed to the console.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Uh oh though. In retrospect a bad idea, but after saving geocodenew.Rda I re-made geocode as a NEW FILE and saved that to geocodenewer.Rda. Is there any way to recover both of these?

Comment: load them into separate sessions or look at the `environment` parameter for `load` and load one of them into a new/separate environment

Comment: Actually, I figured it out!! Your advice was just what I needed to hear. I should be referencing 'geocode' not 'geocodenew.' Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `saveRDS` if you would like to save a specific object with a specific filename. e.g. `saveRDS(geocode, file=paste0('path/geocodenew.rds')` and then to read it back in `geocodenew <- readRDS('path/geocodenew.rds')`.